# Is it worth it to dual wield submachine guns?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

Using the Kiparis (or any other SMG for that matter), is it efficient (or at least balanced) to use the Dual Wield attachment? Is the extra firepower worth the loss in accuracy?

I ask this because I don't usually see other players using it, and that makes me think it's probably under-balanced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've had some really good gameplay in confined spaces where you can spray and pray. I use scavenger pro, steady aim pro, marathon pro with radar equipment and it usually works pretty well. They are pretty worthless for medium to far range, so that's why people probably don't use them.

Comment: why not use a shotgun then?

Comment: @liho1eye - Shotguns usually have a slow rate of fire and reload time.

Answer (score 1):

The skorpion sub machine is a great choice for dual wield because of its high damage rate at close quarters.

I usually run a class with Lightweight, Steady Aim and Marathon.  I also carry a tomahawk for quick kills when my guns run out of bullets.

Comment: That's the same class I've been using. I've been testing it with both Dual Wield and Rapid Fire, and I'm not yet sure which one I prefer.

Comment: For a rapid fire setup, I would use the MP5K or AK74u with Warlord to equip rapid fire and extended mags cause they both give you a healthly 45 bullets per clip.